# how to automatically generate scroll bar when window is resized

Tags: css

I have a outer panel and a inner panel. The inner panel contains the actual contents I want to show. The outer panel is basically a wrapper used to generate scroll bar when the window's size is changed to show the inner panel's contents. 
I would like to know I should I set the inner panel and outer panel to achieve this(such as how to set panels' properties such as position property...)? I have already set the outer panel's overflow property to auto, but still not work.

My code is something like below:

```
#out{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 100% ;
    min-height: 724px;
    min-width: 580px;
}

#in{
    position: absolute;
    width: 60% ;
    height: 70%;
    left: 16% ;
    top: 10% ;
}
```

My problem now is when smaller the browser to some degree, the scroll bar will be covered. I would like to know is there any way that makes the scroll bar not be covered?

Comment: Show us some code or we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a fixed width wrapper somewhere in your page. If you replace the width property with max-width, it'll resize itself if the parent element (in this case the window) becomes too small. If the width becomes smaller than it's content, a scrollbar will appear.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4d8Sj/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#outer {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
}
div#inner {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

(making a demo page yourself is useful, to avoid confusion)